# A rose by any other name

Tags: visual, knowledge

...would smell just as sweet.

I have 9 pictures here. Each image is part of a pair, with one odd image out. There is a rule that links each image to its partner. **The goal is to figure out this rule and match each image to its partner.** The pictures are as follows:

[image]

Two pairs come from two different cartoons, one pair comes from a video game and the final pair is from a movie. However, one of the cartoon pairs is also in a video game.

None of the pictures actually come from the fictional works I am referencing. Instead, the link between them can translate to the correct work if you know it.

---

Hints:

> "Ailes noires se lèvent!"
>  Reading off a phone keypad, images 3 and 5 are a pair.

Comment: Do TV serials count as "movies"?

Comment: No, the movie answer was in theaters.

Comment: are all pairs linked by the same rule or different pairs have different rules of linkage ?

Comment: All four pairs are linked in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's time to put this puzzle out of its misery before I forget the answer.

The connection rule is this:

> The images in each pair are each two names for the same character, changed during translation into another language.

So, the connections are as follows:

> Top-left (Martin Yan) and top-middle (Han Emperor) form the first pair. The connection is **Han Solo**, known as **Yan Solo** in the French dub.
>
>  Top-right (Bonnie from FNAF) pairs with middle (Eureka). **Bonnie** from the Pokemon cartoon is known as **Eureka** in the original Japanese.
>
>  Middle-left (A Butterfly) pairs with bottom-middle (Hawk Moth). As was noticed, **Hawk Moth** is a character from Miraculous. In the French version of the show, he is **Le Papillon** (translation: The Butterfly).
>
>  Bottom-left (Diego) and bottom-right (Byrne) are the last pair. **Byrne** from Legend of Zelda: Spirit Tracks is named **Diego** in the Spanish translation of the game.
>
>  The rose (middle-right) is the odd image out, chosen just because it matched the name of the puzzle and completed the 3x3 grid. When I chose it, I did *not* notice Rose Byrne's first name. I would have picked something else if I did.

Comment: So.. the solution form this puzzle relies on _another_ same named character from a random different series you didn't hint at, which just happens to share the other name when translated to _another_ random language you didn't hint at either?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diego_(given_name)) is the list of all characters named diego, by the way. Fiction only on the bottom.

Answer (score 4):

Since finding what the pictures are of isn't the solution, I'm posting that part for others. I can't find the correlations myself. In parenthesis are some additional, if erroneous, information about the picture.

1 (top left)
— Martin Yan (chef; was featured in one Space Ghost Coast to Coast)

2 (top middle)
— Han Dynasty Emperor Gaozu (historical; Disney's Mulan movie)

3 (top right)
— Bonnie the Bunny (videogame series; Five Nights at Freddy's)

4 (middle left)
— Monarch butterfly (genus *Danaus*)

5 (mid–middle)
— main cast of Eureka (T.V. series)

6  (middle right)
— rose (genus *Rosa*)

7  (bottom left)
— Diego the Explorer (cartoon; Dora The Explorer)

8  (bottom middle)
— Hawk & Moth:  ‘Hawk Moth’ (CGI T.V. series; Miraculous: Tales of Ladybug and Cat Noir, *Miraculous: les Adventures de Ladybug et Chat Noir*)

9 (bottom right)
— Rose Byrne (actress)

Comment: Diego, not Dora

Comment: You should consider making this answer a Community Wiki.  Also, spoiler protection?

Comment: @can-ned_food, good idea. I have and thanks for your edits.

Comment: Of course, now that it is a Community answer, it probably doesn't need spoilers.  I shouldn't edit that away, however, because doing such seems to trick the history into thinking that I did more work than actual.

Comment: @can-ned_food, I was going to tell you I didn't think it was a big deal and to go ahead, but then thought, well then I might look lazy. So I took care of it. Thanks.

Comment: "Hawkmoth" is also a character from the kids' cartoon Miraculous Ladybug - 8 and 4 could be connected because they're a moth and a butterfly. (Also, the two Roses could be connected.)

Comment: @Deusovi Yup.  However, I was thinking that the images are paired  because they share a mutual work of fiction — i.e. “comes from”, — and not simply that they both occur in the same artistic medium.

Answer (score 2):

Pairs are:

```
[1][2][3]
[4][1][X]
[3][4][2]
```

Where:

1. Multiple people pictured
2. Portrait
3. Animated character
4. Flighted creatures

and the rose is unmatched.

Comment: Does that mean "all the pairs are right, but one has a wrong reason", or "only one pair is right, but for the wrong reason"?

Comment: @Donnelle Only one pair is right, but none of reasons even resemble the correct ones.